# How to restrict character in a particular cell

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am using a excel. It has name and age column, which allows both number and character while editing. I don't  want to allow number in name column and don't allow text in age column.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LibreOffice, it is straightforward to allow only numbers in the age column.

1. Data -> Validity
2. Allow: Whole Numbers
3. Data: valid range
4. Minimum: 0
5. Maximum: 199

However it does not look like this same approach can be used to limit numbers.

If you are up for a challenge, it should be possible to write an event handler macro that runs whenever a cell value gets modified.  It could verify that the name only has letters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to prevent letters being entered

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(MID("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",ROW($1:$26),1),A1)))=0
```

And this to prevent numbers being entered

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(MID("0123456789",ROW($1:$10),1),A1)))=0
```

both put in as a custom formula in data validation.

I have tested this in Excel 2010. Unfortunately data validation in Open Office doesn't allow a custom formula so libre office is likely to be the same.